# How to write a simple jasmine test for a MVC Controller function (sails.js)

Tags: node.js, tdd, jasmine, sails.js

I wanna do a TDD.
However, I am going to write test on my controller function for my sails.js project

```
/*---------------------
    :: Gamble
    -> controller
---------------------*/
var GambleController = {

  index: function(req, res) {
      res.send('Hello World!');
  }


};
module.exports = GambleController;
```

However , how can i write a test to test index function that output Hello world?
Any one can give a example?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), there are [some example usages](https://github.com/hunterloftis/component-test/blob/master/lib/users/test/controller.test.js), here's one

```
describe('/signout', function() {
  var agent = superagent.agent();
  it('should start with signin', loginUser(agent));
  it('should sign the user out', function(done) {
    agent.get('http://localhost:3000/signout').end(function(err, res) {
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.redirects.should.eql(['http://localhost:3000/']);
      res.text.should.include('Who are you?');
      return done();
    });
  });
  // ...
```

Comment: It is the interesting approach but look more like an acceptance test than unit tests. Do you have solution for last one?

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty simple to stub out the result object:

```
describe('when we get the game controller', function () {
   it ('should return hello world', function (done) {
      GameController.index(null, {
         send: function (message) {
            assert.equal(message, 'Hello World!');
            done();
         };
      });
   });
});
```